# SMIL Animation Not Ending On Mouseout

Tags: css, svg, smil

I'm trying to make an SVG icon that animates using SMIL (well, I don't care if it's SMIL or CSS, I just don't want to use JS) on hover and I've gotten pretty far but I've run into a problem that I can't find answered or even mentioned online. The animation starts on mouseover (hover) but on mouseout one of the animated elements (2nd circle) keeps animating and I'm at a total loss as to why.

You can also see it at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmjpVQ

Thanks for any help you can provide in advance.

```css
svg { width: 100px; color: red; }
```

```html
<svg id="location" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 60 60">
<defs>
    <clipPath id="circleClip">
        <path d="M49,19c0,7-12,26-18.97,26C23,45,12,26,12,19H49z M72-12h-84v84h84V-12z" />
    </clipPath>
</defs>
<g clip-path="url(#circleClip)">
    <g transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 0.43999, 0, 25.2)">
        <circle transform="rotate(-90, 30, 47)" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" cx="30" cy="47" r="14">
          <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="r" from="0" to="20" begin="location.mouseover" end="location.mouseout" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
          <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" begin="location.mouseover" end="location.mouseout" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </circle>
        <circle transform="rotate(-90, 30, 47)" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" cx="30" cy="47" r="0">
          <animate ttributeType="XML" attributeName="r" from="0" to="20" begin="location.mouseover+2s" end="location.mouseout" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
          <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" begin="location.mouseover+2" end="location.mouseout" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </circle>
    </g>
</g>

    <path fill="currentColor" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="0" d="M30,7c7.18,0,13,5.82,13,13S30,45,30,45S17,27.18,17,20S22.82,7,30,7z" />
    <path fill="#fff" stroke-width="0" d="M30,15c2.76,0,5,2.24,5,5s-2.24,5-5,5c-2.76,0-5-2.24-5-5S27.24,15,30,15" />

</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trap you got caught in was that, unlike HTML elements, mouse events are raised as a default only when the pointer is over an area that is painted (stroke or fill)., but no matter what `opacity` is set to. You can even fine-tune [`pointer-events`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty) to either include or exclude events for `visibility: hidden` or `fill: none`.

The `mouseover` event is raised every time the spreading circle you animated passes under the pointer, With `pointer-events:all` you could prevent `mousout` when the mouse ends up over the interior, but only until the animation repeat resets the radius. This makes things pretty confusing.

The most simple solution is to lay an invisible rect with `opacity="0"` on top of the whole icon, so that there are clearly defined borders for "inside" and "outside". For more finetuning, define a shape that covers the area where you want to capture mouse moves.

```css
svg { width: 100px; color: red; }
```

```html
<svg id="loc" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 60 60">
<defs>
    <clipPath id="c">
        <path d="M49,19c0,7-12,26-18.97,26C23,45,12,26,12,19H49z M72-12h-84v84h84V-12z" />
    </clipPath>
</defs>
<g clip-path="url(#c)">
    <g transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 0.43999, 0, 25.2)">
        <circle transform="rotate(-90, 30, 47)" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" cx="30" cy="47" r="14">
          <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="r" from="0" to="20" begin="loc.mouseover" end="loc.mouseout" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
          <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" begin="loc.mouseover" end="loc.mouseout" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </circle>
        <circle transform="rotate(-90, 30, 47)" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" cx="30" cy="47" r="0">
          <animate ttributeType="XML" attributeName="r" from="0" to="20" begin="loc.mouseover+2s" end="loc.mouseout" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
          <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" begin="loc.mouseover+2" end="loc.mouseout" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </circle>
    </g>
</g>

    <path fill="currentColor" stroke="currentColor" d="M30,7c7.18,0,13,5.82,13,13S30,45,30,45S17,27.18,17,20S22.82,7,30,7z" />
    <path fill="#fff" d="M30,15c2.76,0,5,2.24,5,5s-2.24,5-5,5c-2.76,0-5-2.24-5-5S27.24,15,30,15" />
    <rect opacity="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That was incredibly helpful.

Comment: @ccprog pointer-events can be used so that mouseover works on areas that are fill=none